# Java 1.8.121 does not work on linux - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, linux

Downloaded latest java SE version (1.8.0_121) for linux x86 from Oracle website.

Extracted the RPM.

When trying to run:

```
my_extracted_folder/bin/java
```

Getting only this:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

My linux version:

```
Linux nps19 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

No idea what to do. An older version on the machine seems to be working fine.

Comment: Extracted or Installed the RPM? RPM performs some activities to prepare the environment for the newly installed java environment. Also, have you run ControlPanel in the bin directory?

Answer (score 0):

You have a machine running `64 bit processor`.But it seems that you have downloaded the `32 bit version of java` (x86) .For a 64 bit architecture, you have to install both the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version of jre. `rt.jar` file or architecture independent files are only distributed for 32 bit version and is not included in jre package for 64 bit. So either you install jre for both 32 and 64 and retry or download the new 64 bit version from the official site.